# how to convert string in string array?

Tags: java, string, arrays

suppose I am getting 2 strings

```
"About product" and "About Us"
```

and I want to store them in `String` array like

```
myArray[]={"About product", "About Us"};
```

how to do this?

Comment: why dont you store them in `String` ?

Comment: You can use Collection instead of array and use Collection.add(Object) method for dynamic needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading strings dynamically, and you want to end up with an array of them (`String[]`), but you don't know how many there are until you've read them all.

In Java, arrays are of fixed length, so the answer is *not* to store them in an array until you know how many there are.  What you need is a temporary **list**.  There are several lists you can use, depending upon certain performance characteristics, but the `ArrayList` is a reasonable choice.

```
ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

will create a new array list.  Then in a loop you can read a string and add it to the list (which will expand to accommodate each new entry):

```
arrList.add(str);
```

and then you can create and fill the array you *really* wanted. There is a convenience method on `List`s for doing this, like this:

```
String[] strArray = arrList.toArray(new String[arrList.size()]);
```

It is not obvious at first glance why the `toArray` method needs to have the array passed to it, but it makes the call typesafe, and you don't have to cast the result to `String[]`.  You can read the JavaDoc for this method [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29).

Answer (score 4):

The code you've shown at the end is almost correct already. If you're declaring the variable at that point you can use:

```
String[] myArray = { firstString, secondString };
```

Otherwise (if it's declared elsewhere) you can use:

```
myArray = new String[] { firstString, secondString };
```

If this isn't what you're trying to achieve, please clarify your question.

Comment: i am getting strings dynamically. at first i do not know how many strings i will be getting.

Comment: Soniya: this is a new requirement, please amend the question.

Comment: @Soniya: In that case you need to provide a lot more information. How are you getting the strings? At what point do you know how many you've got? Can you use a `List<String>` instead of an array? Please read http://tinyurl/so-hints for what makes a good question, and then edit your question appropriately.

Comment: I don't knew that this syntax of array declaration too works in C#. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] myArray = {"About product","About Us"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it directly just by doing

```
String[] myArray={"About product", "About Us"};
```

If you mean you get the Strings at run time you can just do:

```
String[] myArray = new String[2];

myArray[0] = s1;
myArray[1] = s2;
```

Comment: I am doing 
String myArray[]={};
and then adding Strings to myArray in a loop.
it's not working.

Comment: What you need is to allocate memory at run time because during compile time you don't know the data that you're going to store. This is done using the constructor (String myArray[] = new String[N]). String myArray[]={} won't work because you're allocating memory statically. You can only do that if you know what strings you'll save (String[] myArray={"About product", "About Us"} is OK because you are specifying the strings at that point). Hope this makes sense.